# I just want to randomly click some button and then when I click Sum button it will show the sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I just want to randomly click some button and then when I click Sum button it will show the sum of clicked button value result, I need this code with java script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var mynum = new Array(6);
var i = 0;

unction buttonClicked(obj) {
if (i < mynum.length) 
 mynum[i++] = obj.value; 
else alert("Array limit reached");
}

function sum() {
sumOfArray = 0;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
sumOfArray += parseInt(mynum[j++]);
alert("Sum = " + sumOfArray);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<p id="demo">Result</p>


button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(2)">1</button>

<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(3)">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(3)">4</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(3)">8</button>


<button type="button" onclick="sum()">Sum</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say you want to click randomly, you mean you want _the user_ to be able to click buttons at random, right? Not that you want to apply JS's `Math.random()` to programmatically click things? Try `mynum[i++] = obj` in your function, since the values you are passing in the `obj` argument are numbers...

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
unction buttonClicked(obj) {
```

should be:

```
function buttonClicked(obj) {
```

---

As you are sending the value to the function, and not an object containing the value, this:

```
mynum[i++] = obj.value;
```

should be:

```
mynum[i++] = obj;
```

---

As you have numbers in the array, you shouldn't parse them. This:

```
sumOfArray += parseInt(mynum[j++]);
```

should be:

```
sumOfArray += mynum[j++];
```

Side note: When you do use `parseInt` you should specify the base as the second parameter, otherwise it will parse numbers that start with a zero using base 8 instead of 10.

---

You probably want to send a value to the function that corresponds to what the button shows, so this:

```
button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(2)">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(3)">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(3)">4</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(3)">8</button>
```

should be:

```
<button onclick="buttonClicked(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="buttonClicked(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="buttonClicked(4)">4</button>
<button onclick="buttonClicked(8)">8</button>
```

Comment: @Dampsquid: Good point, but that depends on whether you want to start over, or continue to add more values.

Comment: If I want only Sum of button value by random button click like calculator, how would be the code??